# GWT - HTML widget - setEnabled

Tags: gwt

Is there a way to make `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML` widget being enabled or not-enabled? I tried but there seems no setEnabled(boolean) method :S Share your experience please

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by enabled? Visible?

Comment: No, 'enabled true/false' means can/cannot be clicked or mouse pressed etc (widget events support)

Comment: Have you still not found a single answer here useful!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by enabled but I'll take a stab at it.

I assume that you mean visible or not visible.

```java
HTMLPanel panel = new HTMLPanel();
panel.setVisible(false); // Disabled
panel.setVisible(true);  // Enabled
```

Hopefully that's what you were looking for.

Comment: No, I mean not the 'visible/invisible' but enable means 'cannot be clicked like Button widget if setEnabled(false)'

Comment: OK well there's no such method in Widget as others have said. You'll have to implement it on your own.

Comment: Well I know there is 'no such a method' :) I am not pretty sure how to make it support this kind of method? Maybe you know some code samples in this direction because I couldn't find any myself :S

Answer (score 0):

Only a few HTML elements can be enabled or disabled, like inputs. GWT has setEnabled() for elements that can get focus:

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusWidget.html#setEnabled(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

Only some form elements(inputs, options) can be disabled.

To disable:

```
widget.getElement().setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
```

To enable again:

```
widget.getElement().removeAttribute("disabled");
```

For other widget, you need to set their style to mimic "disabling". (e.g. set the color to grey)

Comment: No, I mean 'enabled true/false not for color' but make it enable for mouse events for example etc

Comment: Will it change the widget color to make it look like really 'disabled' like Button does when it is button.setEnabled(false)?

Comment: @user592704 Yes it will. If you just want to disable the events, you just need to do `unsinkEvents`

Comment: but is there a way to restore fired events back? I mean fire events and add them again is quite none-optimal thing

Answer (score 0):

### **To Give appearance of enable and disable feature in a widget which does not inherit from** [FocusWidget](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusWidget.html).

You would need to override both style and event handling implementation. Keep a `enableFl` in your `MyHTMLPanel extends HTMLPanel`.

**Step 1** - Provide enable and disable style. Using opacity css turn on/off greying sort of coloring. Based on state of enableFl turn on/off the enable/disable feature.

**Step 2** - Disable/Enable event handling on the widget by overriding `onBrowserEvent` and making its execution conditional on your own enableFl state.

**Step 3** - Recursively disable all widgets internal to HTMLPanel.

If your use case is simple you might opt to use **com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML** instead of **com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLPanel** .

Comment: Thank you. It is quite interesting but could you show some code snippet(s)?

Comment: I am not pretty sure what you mean. The question is about the HTML widget... The thing is to make HTML widget become disable as Button widget does when you invoke button.setEnabled(false) method for example... I couldn't find any useful code samples in this direction for HTML widget so maybe I missed something... ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such a method in Widget.

But there is a little room to acheive .I made it work with help of google groups

```
public void setEnabled (boolean e)
 {
  Iterator<Widget> itr = grd.iterator (); // grd is a FlexTable which
contains my form controls

  while (itr.hasNext ())
  {
   Widget w = itr.next ();

   if (w instanceof TextBox)
   {
    TextBox t = (TextBox) w;
    t.setEnabled (e);
   }

   if (w instanceof PasswordTextBox)
   {
    PasswordTextBox t = (PasswordTextBox) w;
    t.setEnabled (e);
   }

  ...
  }
```